# How does Windows treat these paths and how to emulate?

Tags: windows-10, path, windows-libraries

Within **Windows Explorer** folder/libraries for folder such as *Desktop*, *Downloads*, *Documents*, *Images*, *3D Objects*, *Music* and *Videos*, etc. one can simply type these names and press **Enter** and easily get there and/or have the folder open.

I thought this as common behavior for all libraries, but *Downloads* nor *3D Objects* are libraries on **Windows**.

Also, all these folders are listed under "**This PC**".

Pictures for reference:

[image]

[image]

**How Windows treats these folder paths?** e.g. a symlink.

**How to replicate this behavior?**

PS: For any other name typed will go to http://name/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replicate this behavior to work just as you describe when typing in the folder name into **Run** (e.g. **Desktop**, **Music**, etc.) and pressing enter to open those up you can simply use [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) and create a directory junction or a symbolic folder link to the folder on the root of the [user profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) directory.

```
mklink /d "%userprofile%\<Name>" "<C:\FolderPath\ToLink>"
```

or

```
mklink /j "%userprofile%\<Name>" "<C:\FolderPath\ToLink>"
```

Now from  **Run** you can type in the name of the link and press Enter and it'll open that folder just as it does for **Desktop**, **Music**, or any other folder or link  on the root of the user profile directory.

Actually, you could create the link in any folder that's in the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environmental variable and it'll work just the same but I provided what matches the folders you gave examples.

---

### Further Resources

- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)
- **`mklink /?`**

  > ```
  > Creates a symbolic link.
  >
  > MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
  >
  >         /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
  >                 symbolic link.
  >         /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
  >         /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
  >         Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
  >         Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
  >                 refers to.
  > ```